# Losing focus after keystroke in the input component, but works fine with inline JSX

Tags: reactjs, focus

[image]

Hi, I want to build a Page with multiple inputs. However, the MyInput component will lose its focus after every keystroke while the inline JSX works fine as above.

The MyInput component is basically as same as the inline JSX, I've no idea why it loses the focus.

You could check the source code from [the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-snowflake-2c3sps?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Move `MyInput` declaration outside of `App` function. You can't declare a component inside another component

Comment: > Move MyInput declaration outside of App function. You can't declare a component inside another component

@Konrad, could you please check the codesandbox, it works fine with the MyInput declaration inside the App(), and the focus issue is still there after moving the MyInput out of App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";


function MyInput({
  label,
  value,
  onDataChange
}: {
  label: string;
  value: number;
  onDataChange: (type: string, amount: number) => void;
}) {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(value);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Component input: </div>
      <label>{label}: </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={amount ?? 0}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const i = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);
          if (Number.isNaN(i)) return;
          setAmount(i);
          onDataChange("distance", i);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [log, setLog] = useState({
    id: "",
    distance: 0,
    duration: 0,
    weight: 0
  });

  function handleLogDataChange(type: string, amount: number) {
    setLog({ ...log, [type]: amount });
  }



  const [distance, setDistance] = useState(log.distance);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>The distance is {log.distance}</div>
      <div>
        <div>Inline input: </div>
        <span>Distance: </span>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={distance ?? 0}
          onChange={(e) => {
            const i = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);
            if (Number.isNaN(i)) return;
            setDistance(i);
            handleLogDataChange("distance", i);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <MyInput
        label="Distance"
        value={log.distance}
        onDataChange={handleLogDataChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

just removed MyInput outside of the app. Do not declare a component inside a component